# GetType() on Array item?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an initialised array that may contain no items.

Lets call it `a`,

Calling `GetType()` on `a` will obviously return a type of Array. Is it possible to get the type of the items the array contains?

Obviously `a[0].GetType()` would work, but then the array could be empty and cause a null reference exception.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Well, you can get the [element type of the array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getelementtype.aspx):

```
Type type = array.GetType().GetElementType();
```

(That's not quite the same as getting the types of the items in the array - an `object[]` may be entirely populated with strings, for example.)

Comment: @Kryptos Wow, of course it works. I must have made a ridiculously stupid comment 2 years ago, which I am deleting now. God knows which bug back then led to writing that.

Comment: @Kryptos Then again, why does the bottom of the linked article say that it "returns null for the Array class"?

Comment: @relatively_random maybe the doc is obsolete...
The reference source does show that the type construction of an array uses the item type as "compound type":
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/emit/typebuilder.cs,1483

Answer (score 14):

Maybe [Type.GetElementType()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getelementtype.aspx) is what you need.