# How do you get the Element Type of an Empty Array in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection

```
Int32[] myArray = new Int32[0];

//Somewhere else in code: 
Type t = myArray.GetType();

//t == Int32[]
//element type of t == ???
```

How do I find out the element type that t was created to store.

The only example I've found works on arrays that aren't empty, where you simply do myArray[i].GetType().  So what do you do for array length 0?

FYI: I did the following and it works fine, but wow... it uses string conversion and is super ugly. There's got to be a better way:

```
Type t = myArray.GetType();
string strT = t.ToString();
string strArrayBase = strT.Substring(0, strT.Length - 2);
Type elementType = Type.GetType(strArrayBase);
```

Comment: [There](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085172/) [is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347053/) [so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129831/) [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840878/) [duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267676/) [on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274865/) [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28624571/) [overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19072056/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.GetElementType()`

Eg:

```
> int[] arr = new int[0];
> arr.GetType().GetElementType()
[System.Int32]
```

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getelementtype?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Wow.  Fail.  I actually looked at the doc on GetElementType(), but the explanation for it seemed kind of confusing. And on some other thread, someone was actually saying not to use it for a similar purpose.  So I wasn't sure what to make of it.  I just tried it and it works!  I feel dumb now.  Thanks!